# jQuery change the text inside my <span>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following html code:

```
<span id="change_user_status_account-1">
    SIMPLE TEXT INSIDE SPAN
</span>

<span id="change_user_status_account-2">
    SIMPLE TEXT INSIDE SPAN
</span>
```

now with jQuery I want to change the text inside `<span>` tag. But my code doesn't work:

```
$('[id^="change_user_status_account-"]').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-');
    alert(id[1]);
    $("change_user_status_account-" + id[1]).html('OK CHANGED');
});
```

`alert()` in this code return `1` or `2` and I don't get any error on `FireBug`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a `#` before your `id`

```
$('[id^="change_user_status_account-"]').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-');
    alert(id[1]);
    $("#change_user_status_account-"+id[1]).html('OK CHANGED');
});
```

Or Just Do

```
$('[id^="change_user_status_account-"]').click(function () {
    $(this).html('OK CHANGED');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(this)`. `$(this)` inside the event handler refers to the element on which the event has occurred.

```
$('[id^="change_user_status_account-"]').click(function () {
    $(this).text('changed');
});
```

I'd recommend to use a common class on both the elements and bind event using class.

```js
$('.sample').on('click', function() {
  $(this).text(+new Date());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="sample">
    SIMPLE TEXT INSIDE SPAN
</span>

<span class="sample">
    SIMPLE TEXT INSIDE SPAN
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are missing `#` in selector

it should be

```
$("#change_user_status_account-" + id[1]).html('OK CHANGED');
```

or try

```
$('[id^="change_user_status_account-"]').click(function () {
    $(this).html('OK CHANGED');
});
```